# IF ELIF blocks based on multiple conditions throwing error " ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

Tags: python, if-statement

I want an output dataframe which outputs class(a column in dataframe) based on ML model predictions and rule based model based on different conditions on the input dataframe. I have written the below code which needs correction as per python standards. Could someone please assist in rephrasing the code.

```
def func1(model_file_path,prep_df,df):
        if ((df['col']=='val1') | (df['col']=='val2') |(df['col']=='val3')) :
                df['predicted']='category1'
                df['indicator']='rule_based'
         elif ((df['col']=='val4') | (df['col']=='val5') |(df['col']=='val6')):
            # saved model file path
             file_path=model_file_path
            
            # load the saved model
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                model = pickle.load(f)
            
            predictions=model.predict(prep_df)
            prep_df['predicted']=predictions
            prep_df['indicator']='ML_based'
        else:
            print('value not in df')
    
        # combined output df
        df_out=pd.concat([df,prep_df])
        return df_out
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: thanks for the response. I had used any() as per the above doc but getting the below output

Comment: | col1   | predicted  |  indicator  |
| ------ | ----------- | ------------|
| val4   | category1 | rule_based |
| val5   | category1 | rule_based |

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify anything about it.